# Writing XML files?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to write XML files.

I've got a list of Configuration.

```
[Serializable]
public class Configuration
{
    public decimal X { get; set; }
    public decimal Y { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my property.

```
    [XmlArray("Configurations")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Configuration")]
    public List<Configuration> Configurations { get;set; }
```

The caller is:

```
    this.Configurations = new List<Configuration>()
    {
        new Configuration() { X = 1, Y = 10 },
        new Configuration() { X = 10, Y = 100 },
    };

    string filename = "test.xml";

    TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename);
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Configuration>));
    serializer.Serialize(writer, this.Configurations));
    writer.Close();
```

And the output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfConfiguration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Configuration x="1" y="10" />
  <Configuration x="10" y="100" />
</ArrayOfConfiguration>
```

There's a way that can generate this XML file?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<Configurations>
  <Configuration X="1" Y="10" />
  <Configuration X="10" Y="100" />
</Configurations>
```

Is there a way to generate them in this way?

Comment: Yes. Do the serialization manually ;-)

Comment: I have no idea about that way, how would be?

Comment: Why doesn't the second `<Configuration>` have the attributes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use following attributes:

```
[XmlArray("Configurations")]
[XmlArrayItem("Configuration")]
```

Comment: One doubt, it works for me when I serialize an object which contains the list. Is possible to serialize the property directly?

Comment: I am not sure is this what you have in mind: [XmlRootAttribute("Configurations")]                                   
    public class ConfigurationCollection : List<Configuration>
    {

    }